# SaltStack: normalize Package name

Tags: saltstack

I would like to have less conditions in my saltstack sls files.

Up to now it looks like this:

```
foo_package:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:  
  {% if grains.os_family == 'Debian' %}
      - foo_BAR
  {% else %}
      - foo-bar
  {% endif %}
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
foo_package:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:  
      - {{ foo_BAR | normalize_package_name }}
```

How to implement `normalize_package_name`?

As soon as I can use Python I can help myself and implement this very easily: Underscores should get replaced with `-` and upper case characters should get lower case.

I know that I could do it in Jinja like this:

```
- {{ foo_BAR | replace... | replace .. }}
```

But this gets used several times, that's why I would like to have a custom filter.

.... some days later: Maybe it is better to write a custom state (`mypkg.installed`) and call `pkg.installed` after normalizing the package names. See salt docs: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/writing.html#cross-calling-state-modules

Answer (score 1):

In your case I think the best is to use the possibilities offered by 'formulas'. You can transform your standalone states in a formula and use a map.jinja to specify the package name depending of the OS or other grains values.

As an example you can look on https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/template-formula/ which implements it. Look at `template/map.jinja` and `template/defaults.yaml` and `template/os*.yaml` files